# I am trying to create a splash screen for my app but i am getting AAPT: error: not well-formed error

Tags: android, android-studio

**Here is my splash screen xml code**
I am trying to create a splash screen activity here a bit differently. I am using a drawable splash xml file , which i will set as a theme and then use it as a launcher activity which will lead to my main activity. But my drawable xml file is throwing the eroor AAPT: error: not well-formed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>

    <item android:drawable=”@color/colorPrimary” />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity=”center”
            android:src=”@mipmap/ic_launcher” />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

---

got the issue  instead of XML , a PNG should be there in android:src=”@mipmap/ic_launcher” />

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **"** instead of **”**.

I think that **”** is not a valid character for *xml* values.

Comment: na i got the issue. Instead of XML , a png should be there in src

Answer (score 0):

got the issue instead of XML , a PNG should be there in android:src=”@mipmap/ic_launcher” />